# Topic: querying in Firebase Android - data retrieval

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase database format:

> -groups
>   -groupName
>     -groupId
>       -key1:"value1"         -key2:"value2"
>       -key3:"value3"

I need to access `value3` of `key3`.

I have the `groupId`.

Below is the code I've come up with. But when I run this my screen keeps crashing.

```
    private void method_does_user_belong_to_this_group() {
        expected_key3 = editText_expected_key3.getText().toString();
        reference.child("groups").orderByChild(groupId+"/"+"key3").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    key3 = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                    if (key3.equals(expected_key3)) {
                        Toast.makeText(RoomJoiningPage.this, "Key3 found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(RoomJoiningPage.this, "Key3 not found"+key3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else  {
                    Toast.makeText(RoomJoiningPage.this, "Key3 not found"+key3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

I've even tried this part too:

```
GroupDataClass groupDataClass = snapshot.getValue(GroupDataClass.class);
String key3 = groupDataClass.getKey();
```

by omitting this part from the above method:

```
key3 = snapshot.getValue().toString();
```

But even then my screen keeps crashing.
Any help is sincerely appreciated.

**Edit-1**
I've tried editing the code a bit so far. Now the crashing has stopped but the value I'm receiving is "null".

```
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Debug Count - 12");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Entered else but didnt run the code below");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Code entered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        reference_to_rooms_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("rooms");
        reference_to_rooms_db.orderByChild(string_current_users_number).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"went inside \"onDataChanged\"");
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"went inside \"if\"");
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"snapshot existed");
                    code = snapshot.child("code").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"code copied - "+code+".");
                    Toast.makeText(RoomJoiningPage.this, "added code:"+code, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"toasted within \"if\"");
                }
                else {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"went inside \"else\"");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"went inside \"onCancelled\"");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you check if your snapshot getting data or no ?

Comment: @Ashish Using snapshot I'm getting a null value.

Comment: Your query is invalid. So better provide groupname with it

Comment: @Ashish Could you plz provide an example with reference to the DB structure that I showed at the start. I just learnt firebase stuff just 2 days back. So I'm still not familliar with the ins n outs of queying here.

Comment: Join room : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225823/new-guy-to-firebase